# Assignment Operator Overload in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I realize that there are examples after examples of overloading the assignment operator on the web, but I have spent the last few hours trying to implement them in my program and figure out how they work and I just can't seem to do it and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to implement an overloaded assignment operator function.

I have 3 files working, the Complex.h header file, a Complex.cpp definition file, and a .cpp file I'm using as a driver to test my Complex class.

In the Complex.h header file my prototype for the assignment operator:

```
Complex &operator= (Complex&);
```

And so far what I have for the definition of the overloaded operator in my .cpp file is:

```
    Complex &Complex::operator=(Complex& first)
    {
         if (real == first.real && imaginary == first.imaginary)
             return Complex(real, imaginary);

         return first;
    };
```

And the way I'm calling my assignment operator in my functions is:

```
   x = y - z;
```

So specifically, my problem is that when I call the overloaded assignment operator with x = y -z, it doesn't assign the passed in value to x when I return the passed in value and I'm unable to figure out why from numerous examples and explanations on the web, any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you for any help ahead of time.

Comment: Why don't you read some of those examples after examples and model your assignment operator on one that actually works?

Comment: `=` shouldn't probably modify its right hand operand.

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried that, and I apologize for this and sincerely appreciate your input, but my brain just doesn't work this way, I did try to read those examples and model after those working examples but it would end in recursion.

Comment: @zenith So you're saying that by returning first I am modifying the right hand operand?

Comment: No, he clearly does not modify the right-hand-operand.

Comment: You're returning a *reference* to the right hand operand which could then be modified. `operator=` should take a `const Complex&`.

Comment: It could be modified, but he doesn't actually modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the following operator definition

```
Complex & Complex::operator =( const Complex &first )
{
     real = first.real;
     imaginary = first.imaginary;

     return *this;
};
```

You have to return reference to the object that is assigned to.  Also the parameter should be a constant reference. In this case you may bind the reference to a temporary object or you have to write also a move assignment operator.

In your implementation of the copy assignment operator you do not change the assigned object.:) You simply create a temporary and return reference to this temporary or return reference to first.

Comment: Whilst strictly accurate, this isn't that helpful as it doesn't really explain to the OP why you've written it that way.

Comment: If I understand your method correctly I should assign to the real and imaginary private data members to create a new Complex object and then return the created Complex object with the address of the current (this) data member?

Comment: @DastardlyDeedDoer No, assignment should not create a new object (unless as an intermediary implementation detail). It *assigns* a value to an existing one.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're saying I'm creating a new object by returning first? But isn't it already created because I called the overloaded operator with it? So I'm just returning the passed in value? Or is my understanding of this way off?

Comment: @DastardlyDeedDoer No, I am saying you don't create an new object and you shouldn't. I mean, you in your broken code do, but the code in this answer doesn't.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, thank you very much. I'm going to mark this response as the answer because I tried it and it works well, but @πάντα ῥεῖ also has a response that works. I appreciate all the input and the swift response from you all, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment takes in two objects, the object to be assigned to, and the object with the desired value.

Assignment should:

- modify an existing object, the object being assigned to

Assignment should not:

- create a new object
- modify the object that has the desired value.

So let's say the object type we're dealing with is:

```
struct S {
  int i;
  float f;
};
```

A function that performs assignment might have the signature:

```
void assignment(S &left_hand_side, S const &right_hand_side);
```

And it would be used:

```
S a = {10, 32.0f};

S b;

assignment(b, a);
```

Notice:

- the left hand side object is modifiable, and assignment will modify it, rather than create a new object.
- the right hand side object, the object with the desired value, is not modifiable.

Additionally, in C++ the built-in assignment operation is an expression rather than a statement; it has a value and can be used as a subexpression:

```
int j, k = 10;

printf("%d", (j = k));
```

This sets j equal to k, and then takes the result of that assignment and prints it out. The important thing to note is that the result of the assignment expression *is the object that was assigned to*. No new object is created. In the above code, the value of `j` is printed (which is 10, because `j` was just assigned the value 10 from `k`).

Updating our earlier assignment function to follow this convention results in a signature like:

S &assignment(S &left_hand_side, S const &right_hand_side);

An implementation looks like:

```
S &assignment(S &left_hand_side, S const &right_hand_side) {
  // for each member of S, assign the value of that member in 
  // right_hand_side to that member in left_hand_side.
  left_hand_side.i = right_hand_side.i;
  left_hand_side.f = right_hand_side.f;

  // assignment returns the object that has been modified
  return left_hand_side;
}
```

Note that this assignment function is not recursive; it does not use itself in the assignment, but it does use assignment *of the member types*.

The final piece of the puzzle is getting the syntax `a = b` to work, instead of `assignment(a, b)`. In order to do this, all you have to do is make `assignment ()` a member function:

```
struct S {
  int i;
  float f;

  S &assignment(S &left_hand_side, S const &right_hand_side) {
    left_hand_side.i = right_hand_side.i;
    left_hand_side.f = right_hand_side.f;
    return left_hand_side
  }
};
```

Replace the `left_hand_side` argument with `*this`:

```
struct S {
  int i;
  float f;

  S &assignment(S const &right_hand_side) {
    this->i = right_hand_side.i;
    this->f = right_hand_side.f;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

And rename the function to `operator=`:

```
struct S {
  int i;
  float f;

  S &operator=(S const &right_hand_side) {
    this->i = right_hand_side.i;
    this->f = right_hand_side.f;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main() {
  S a, b = {10, 32.f};

  S &tmp = (a = b);

  assert(a.i == 10);
  assert(a.f == 32.f);

  assert(&tmp == &a);
}
```

Another important thing to know is that the `=` sign is used in one place that is not assignment:

```
S a;
S b = a; // this is not assignment.
```

This is 'copy initialization'. It does not use `operator=`. It is not assignment. Try not to confuse the two.

Points to remember:

- assignment modifies the object being assigned to
- assignment does not modify the object being assigned from.
- assignment does not create a new object.
- assignment is not recursive, except insofar as assignment of a compound object makes use of assignment on all the little member objects it contains.
- assignment returns the object after modifying its value
- copy initialization looks sort of like assignment, but has little to do with assignment.

Comment: I know this was posted awhile back - but its a really thoughtful answer and should be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

An overloaded assignment operator should look like this:

```
Complex &Complex::operator=(const Complex& rhs)
{
     real = rhs.real; 
     imaginary = rhs.imaginary;
     return *this;
};
```

---

You should also note, that if you overload the assignment operator you should overload the copy constructor for `Complex` in the same manner:

```
Complex::Complex(const Complex& rhs)
{
    real = rhs.real; 
    imaginary = rhs.imaginary;
};
```

Comment: This is a double fail. First, you overloaded `=` but made it do `==`, and secondly, self-assignment is for out-of-date lecturers and not for real-world use

Comment: I have the code for the equality operator working just fine in later code, I need to be able to modify the left hand operand (the x) when I return the value from the assignment operator function.

Comment: @DastardlyDeedDoer _"I need to be able to modify the left hand operand (the x) when I return the value from the assignment operator function."_ My example will exactly do this.

Comment: @Puppy I totally agree and that is a major reason I'm here asking for help, all of the coding I do doesn't do such round about crap. But this is for a class I'm taking and I will get little credit if I don't get this too work. But mostly my reason for the use of the equality operator is to avoid self-assignment, unless I'm going about that the wrong way too.

Comment: @DastardlyDeedDoer I believe you have a misconception what the _left hand_ operand in an assignment statement really is.

Comment: What do you think is passed to `first` in your sample if you have something like `Complex a,b; a = b;` `a` or `b`?

Comment: A Complex object called b that needs to be assigned to Complex object a.

Comment: @DastardlyDeedDoer So what's the problem? That's exactly what my code is doing.

Comment: Well, I thought you were saying that I had a misconception of what the left hand operand in an assignment statement was. To be honest, this conversation took a turn I did not expect.

Comment: @Puppy Well, I removed it. So you meant modern compilers will optimize that before the assignment operator is called at all?

Comment: No, what I meant is that nobody cares. Self-assignment is so rare that checking for it is just slower than not checking for it. On top of that, you get self-assignment-safety for free with a strongly exception safe operator in virtually every case. Furthermore, self-assignment is more of a *bug* rather than a thing. So the general rule is, don't check because it's a tiny edge case and not worth any effort or thought at all that isn't even broken in the first place and can't be optimized for.

Comment: @Puppy There is a very important use case where you simply **have** to check for self-assignment: Job interviews. ;-)